# C# -> Detetcting Browser Width

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, visual-studio

I have a web application in C#. I need to be able to detect the user's browser width. How is this possible? I know that you can detect the browsers width using javascript/jquery....but how can I make this available serve-side (from within my C# code).

Comment: Do you mean something like `screen.width` in js ?

Comment: What's the goal behind this question? There's almost certainly another, less fragile way to achieve it...

Comment: The goal is to pass in a value (width) which can then be used to scale elements within report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a hiddenfield and fill it by using jQuery http://api.jquery.com/width/

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

So you can choose window or document and fill a [hiddenfield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx)

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="Server" Value="" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

Please note that clientidmode is only for asp.net 4 and above
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

```
$("#<%= hf.ClientID %>").val($(window).width()); //asp.net 3.5 or lower
$("#hf").val($(window).width()); //asp.net 4 or higher
```

**edit** another option is to use jquery and do an ajax post to an *.ashx or *.asmx

Comment: i agree that this is the best solution, and if ClientID isn't binding correctly because it is a nested control, you can also find the hidden field dynamically in jQuery. For instance, if you know that there is a wrapper around the hidden field, you could find it like so: $('.wrapper').find('input[type=hidden]'). There are plenty of pseudo-selectors that can be leveraged based on the pattern found.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible unless you combine client script functionality with server side code.

You could probably use JQuery to get browser width and set it to a hidden field.
http://api.jquery.com/width/

The thing is that you would not have that value on pageLoad, but only after page is rendered, JQuery initialized and postBack created.

Does that help?

Comment: +1 This is the only flow that will get you an answer but it's also fragile - what happens if the user has JS turned off. For that matter, what happens if another app accesses your page? There might not be a browser window at all... Also, what if the window has a zoom applied? do you want the real size or the scaled size?

Comment: That's very valid. Regardless of which way you choose there's no "safe" way of getting that value - it can always be hijacked by 3rd party....

Comment: Actually...going deeper into the problem. what are you trying to achieve? Maybe what you need can be done with CSS/Javascript (is that's purely UI related)?

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution could be get screen size from javascript and call a method on server (using Jquery) that will save the details in the session.

Can you explain, for what purpose do you want use this value in the Server side code?

If you want to control placement of elements on the page etc. you could use Media Query that will resize your control according to the browser width.

Answer (score -1):

On server side try these three properties

```
    Request.Browser.ScreenCharactersHeight;
    Request.Browser.ScreenCharactersWidth;
    Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth;
```

Comment: I think you'll find that's .Net 1.1 only and is related to mobile devices... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa710891%28v=vs.71%29.aspx To top it off, it's just a guesstimate